# Button on click event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

I use button onClick event which seems that its not working like I expect ,

I've read many post in SO and try many things but its still not working ,what can couse this issue?

```
<input type="button" value="button text" onclick="CallFunc()" />
```

Any idea,why?

Comment: What is your JS function?  The html looks (semantically) correct, although using onclick event handlers is quite outdated.

Comment: Post the CallFunc code

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="button text"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e){
  //your codes
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that it's better to use something  like following

Give an ID to your button/table/etc ,here is example.

```
var $table = $("#dataTable").
```

Then call to the function like following

```
  $table.on("click", ".btn-submit", saveNewRow);
```

Try it and let me know.

Good luck!

Comment: jQuery was not tagged

Comment: HI Shimi,Working on that.. I think its look better then the onclick inside the buttons,I'll let you know.

Comment: @Huangism- Correct but I think that in this case it's better to use it like I suggest.

Comment: @ShimiTal it is better but we should not assume the OP knows jquery at all. In this case, the question is now tagged with jquery. An extreme case would be, giving an answer in 1 framework and answering with a totally different framework.

Comment: @Huangism-Yes I miss this part :)